# dataframe %in% dataframe. (R programming)

Tags: r, dataframe, rows

I am trying to extract in a specific way certain rows from a dataset using a logical vector:

```
Logical.vector <- df %in% df[df$a=='ABC123',]
Logical.vector
-----------------------------------------
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Being `df[df$a=='ABC123',]` multiple rows (a "subdataframe") extracted from a dataframe (df) with the next dimensions:

```
ndim(df) 
---------------------------------------
[1] 4226    11
```

Why is my code not obtaining a successful result? Which way could I obtain a logical vector for the rows of the dataframe? Thank you in advance!

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `%in%` works on `vector` and not on a `list` or `data.frame`.  For that we need `==` (but this works only for a single element).  If we want to use `%in%`, then `paste` each row to a single string

```
i1 <- do.call(paste, c(df, sep=", ")) %in% 
             do.call(paste,  c(df[df$a=='ABC123',], sep=", "))
```